# rspec error michael hartl lesson 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

while executing the command

$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

i get this error
/home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/assertions (LoadError)
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`block in require'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`require'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`require'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in`load_dependency'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails.rb:11:in`'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`block in require'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in`require'
    from /home/sarfraz/Desktop/Rails Apps/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sarfraz/Desktop/Rails Apps/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in`require'
    from /home/sarfraz/Desktop/Rails Apps/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in`load'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in`each'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in`run'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/sarfraz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in`block in autorun'

this is my gemfile:
source 'https://rubygems.org'

## Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

## Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

## Use SCSS for stylesheets

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

## Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

## Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

## gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

## Use jquery as the JavaScript library

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

## Use ActiveModel has_secure_password

## gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

## Use unicorn as the app server

## gem 'unicorn'

## Use Capistrano for deployment

## gem 'capistrano', group: :development

## Use debugger

## gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

please help i cannot proceed totally stuck..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems the test/unit libraries are being loaded instead of the RSpec libraries. Review the contents of spec/spec_helper.rb and spec/rails_helper.rb, and the 'require' statements in the spec files to ensure that they match the instructions in the Hartl tutorial. Also, make sure you are using the current tutorial, and the recommended Ruby and Rails versions.

Comment: They match exactly... I actually copy pasted from the tutorial and this is the error. Any help will do.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult for anyone to fix this via a StackOverflow question. I seriously recommend starting over from scratch as the best approach -- you will end up taking less time that way. Uninstall everything and install it again as per the tutorial instructions.